# Finite groups and Normal subgroups - $G$ is a finite group such that $|G|=n$. Let $p$ be the smallest prime such that $p|n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is a finite group such that $|G|=n$. Let $p$ be the smallest prime such that $p|n$. If $H\triangleleft G$ such that $|H|=p$, then prove that $H\subset Z(G)$.

My Work:

Since $|H|$ is a prime $H\cong \mathbb{Z}/(p)$. Hence $H$ is cyclic and abelian. I was stuck afterwards. Can anyone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $N$ be the normalizer of $H$ in $G$ and let $C$ be the centralizer. We are given that $N=G$, and we want to show that $C=G$ as well.

Note that $N/C$ acts by conjugation on $H$, so $N/C$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Aut(H)$. $N=G$, so in fact, $G/C$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Aut(C_p)$, which has order $p-1$. The order of $G/C$ divides both $|G|$ and $p-1$, but since $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, this order must in fact be $1$, so $C=G$, as desired.

Comment: But why cannot $|C/G|$ be another divisor which is not prime?

Comment: Any divisor of $|G|$ which is not $1$ is divisible by a prime which is larger than $p-1$, since $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$.

Answer (score 1):

I write down a proof using the action of $G$ on $H$. I'm new to group theory so that I'm not quite sure if there is any gap in my proof. Any critisism and correction is welcome. Please do not merely down vote.

**Proof:**

Let $G$ act on $H$ by conjugation. By the orbit-stabilizer theorem, any orbit $Gh$ must have length dividing $|G|$. Since also $|Gh| \leq |H| =p$ where $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$, there cannot be any prime divisor of $|G|$ larger than $p$ who also divides $|Gh|$. We conclude that $|Gh| = 1$ or $p$.

If $|Gh| = 1$ for all $h \in H$, then we are done, because that means $g^{-1}hg = h$ for every $h \in H$ and $g \in G$. Suppose that $|Gh| = p$ for some $h \in H$. In that case, the whole $|H|$ forms a single orbit. Therefor the action is transitive. In particular, there exists some $g \in G$ such that $g^{-1}hg = 1$ for some $h \in A \neq 1$, which is absurd, since the only conjugate of $1$ is itself.